# Edit Form Field to show edit or display conditionally through Sharepoint Designer

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation

I am attempting to have a field that is set to `ControlMode="Edit"` by default be conditional to be set to `ControlMode="Display"` based on the value that is set to default above it.

For example: [Field1] is populated by a previous process to either "Yes" or "No".
For [Field2] I would like to to be `ControlMode="Edit"` if [Field1] is set to "Yes" and `ControlMode="Display"` if [Field1] is set to "No". I have tried the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
if ("ff1"="Yes") 
{ <td width="400px" valign="top" class="ms-formbody">
                        <SharePoint:FormField runat="server" id="ff73{$Pos}" ControlMode="Display" FieldName="EMail_x0020_Address" __designer:bind="{ddwrt:DataBind('u',concat('ff73',$Pos),'Value','ValueChanged','ID',ddwrt:EscapeDelims(string(@ID)),'@EMail_x0020_Address')}"/>
                        <SharePoint:FieldDescription runat="server" id="ff73description{$Pos}" FieldName="EMail_x0020_Address" ControlMode="Display"/>
                    </td>
} 
ELSE 
{<td width="400px" valign="top" class="ms-formbody">
                        <SharePoint:FormField runat="server" id="ff73{$Pos}" ControlMode="Edit" FieldName="EMail_x0020_Address" __designer:bind="{ddwrt:DataBind('u',concat('ff73',$Pos),'Value','ValueChanged','ID',ddwrt:EscapeDelims(string(@ID)),'@EMail_x0020_Address')}"/>
                        <SharePoint:FieldDescription runat="server" id="ff73description{$Pos}" FieldName="EMail_x0020_Address" ControlMode="Edit"/>
                    </td>
}
```

I have placed this within the table.

Could anyone help me understand what I am doing wrong and how I can overcome this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a cleaner, pure XSLT way, to achieve what you are trying to do; no need to use javascript. By the way, always remember that XSLT is evaluated and executed first, way before your javascript gets called.

```
<xsl:variable name="ControlMode">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="@Field1 = 'Yes'">
             Edit
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            Display
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>

<SharePoint:FormField runat="server" id="ff73{$Pos}" ControlMode="{$ControlMode}" FieldName="EMail_x0020_Address" __designer:bind="{ddwrt:DataBind('u',concat('ff73',$Pos),'Value','ValueChanged','ID',ddwrt:EscapeDelims(string(@ID)),'@EMail_x0020_Address')}"/>
```

**UPDATE**: how to conditionally highlight a table cell, based on Field1 value

```
<td>
<xsl:if test="@Field1 = 'Yes'">
     <xsl:attribute name="style">background-color:yellow;</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:if>
//this is just for demonstration purpose, it would be better to use a css class, instead of inline style
```

Comment: Thank you MdMazzotti. Where, when editing in Advanced Mode, would this code be placed?

Comment: Yep, I thought you were already there (your custom edit form > Edit file in advanced Mode). Where did you put the code you showed otherwise?

Comment: Sorry, I believe I found where to place it. I placed the code in the <TD> for the field entry. My next question is in your code you reference `test="@Field1 = 'Yes'">` what label would I replace `@Field1` with for the field I need to reference?

Comment: you said "For example: [Field1] is populated by a previous process to either Yes or No". @Field1 is referring to whatever you called [Field1]

Comment: Sorry this is pretty new to me. So do I use the Static Name of "Field1" or the Display Name, or some other ID for "Field1"?

Comment: You must use the Static Name, like this:  @YourStaticName (the @ is required, as it is part of the xslt syntax)

Comment: I got it to work, all through your help. Thank you so much man!!

Comment: no problem, glad I could help

Comment: @CalebFortner I saw your comment, then updated my answer

Comment: I'm used to using `<xsl:value-of...` on display forms, but I can't get this to work on an edit form. When I'm using the xpression builder, it shows each field value properly. But everything is returned as an empty string on the edit form. I'm thinking this could be because of a missing parameter on the edit form since I copied this layout from a new form.

Comment: edit: I found what was missing. I had to replace  `<xsl:call-template name="dvt_1.rowedit"/>` with
`<xsl:for-each select="$Rows">
 <xsl:call-template name="dvt_1.rowedit"/>
</xsl:for-each>`
just before the second set of save/cancel controls.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your script runs once and is not looking for active changes in the form. I used the the jQuery change()function to look for a change in a drop down field (Should not be hard to change to check box). I added the script to the form using a code snippet web part.  When 'translation' is selected it exposes a hidden field to allow a selection of languages. If it is not it hides the extra field.  I got the name of the field (ProjectType_f0f12dc5-0065-49b0-8316-21244af42410_$RadioButtonChoiceField) by using SharePoint Designer to look at the form and get the name.
Code snippet below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function()
      {
          $("h3.ms-standardheader:contains('Requested Language')").closest("tr").hide();

          $('input:radio[name="ProjectType_f0f12dc5-0065-49b0-8316-21244af42410_$RadioButtonChoiceField"]').change(
        function(){

            // checks that the clicked radio button is the one of value 'Yes'
            if ($(this).val() == 'Translation') {

                // If button checked, shows Translation section
                $("h3.ms-standardheader:contains('Requested Language')").closest("tr").show();
            }
            else {

                // if button is not checked the Translation section is hidden
                $("h3.ms-standardheader:contains('Requested Language')").closest("tr").hide();
            }
        });
     });
    </script>
```